# Is it currently possible to enable the mac's integrated graphics chip in a Java application?

Tags: java, macos, gpu

Is there a way to get a Java application to use the integrated, rather than the discrete, GPU on a mac?

(I'm interested in ways to ship an app that won't push the user's Mac laptop into discrete mode, rather than ways to lock in integrated mode on my own laptop for all applications, like gfxCardStatus does.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want is not possible using Java 7.

Some sources from around the web:

- http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2012-September/004863.html
- http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4044

You already mentioned [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io), but that seems to be the only way

Theoretically you can disable [OpenGL support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html), however this is not enough for it to not trigger that java needs discrete graphics. It appears that as part of the evaluation as to whether or not it should use openGL, it tickles the GPU, and the mac decides that it must fire up the discrete GPU for the lifetime of that application.

**edit:** it appears that not even  [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io) can [prevent the switch anymore](https://gfx.io/switching.html#integrated-only-mode-limitations).

Comment: Note that gfxCardStatus doesn't help, you can't force a switch (anymore), since the discrete GPU will always be powered if there is at least one depending app running: https://gfx.io/switching.html#integrated-only-mode-limitations

Comment: `gfxCardStatus` still works just as it did before.  It was never able to switch a running app from discrete to integrated mode, but if you lock it before starting _any_ integrated-unfriendly apps (or close them all, switch to integrated, and restart them), it _will_ keep using the integrated chip.  — @Paul Wagland, Can I suggest removing or changing the edit above?

Comment: (Note, there's a confusing and long-standing issue, where you must select "integrated" two times to get it to lock to that: https://github.com/codykrieger/gfxCardStatus/issues/103 )

Answer (score 2):

There is a special option which has to be specified in the Info.plist file of the launcher of the application:

```
<key>NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching</key><true/>
```

This gives a Java application the power of using the integrated card. Otherwise the system uses the discrete graphics by default. Unfortunately this option is not included in the standard JVM distribution from Oracle.

---

**Update as of 2019-08-01:** The newest generally available macOS + Java today is:
macOS 10.14.6 Mojave + Java Version 8 Update 221 Build 1.8.0_221-b11

Setting `NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching` to `TRUE` indeed prevents the enforced use of discrete GPU usage! But not for all Java apps! I tested these:

**jdiskreport 1.4.1:** After having added `NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching=TRUE` to the `Info.plist` it then launches with the internal GPU and functions normally!

**FreeMind 1.0.1:** `Info.plist` was shipped with `NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching=TRUE` and `NSHighResolutionCapable=TRUE`. Removing `JVMRuntime=jdk1.7.0_45.jdk` starts the app with the iGPU indeed but then does not work. You see the startup dialog ("Freemind 1.0.1": Initializing this, that, bla bla) until the app is ready. But you then only see the main menu (the application stub I guess). No new/recent file opened in a window. As soon as you want to open/create a new file, the creation of a window fails: Short flash and the main menu (the application stub I guess) re-renders shortly. I will ask over at FreeMind what can be done.

Comment: Without support in the Oracle JVM, how are you taking advantage?  We ship with that option set in our application bundle, though it does nothing for now because of the lack of support.

Comment: I have tested this with a standard Java application wrapper for OS X. As far as I understand you can do this if you use a special launcher (wrapper) in front of Java which has its own Info.plist. Then OS X will be free to decide its switching. In the JDK release of Oracle this option is not included in any Info.plist. I raised a bug with Oracle but I am afraid it never will get accepted/reviewed because of Oracles laziness.

Comment: I searched for your bug report and came across the original instead (the same that I linked above) - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041900 - It looks like it's fixed in Java 9!  (Will that obviate your bug?)

Comment: I checked Java from here: https://jdk9.java.net/download
But unfortunately my test app (jdiskreport) runs in an error which I can not debug right now. All I can see the discrete graphics is still activated, so for me it looks like there is no fix within.

Comment: I supplemented the answer with a section "Update as of 2019-08-01". Setting `NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching` to `TRUE` indeed prevents the enforced use of discrete GPU usage. But not for all Java apps. Details in that section.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1108) with the Arduino (Java based) app, always using the high power (external) graphics card.

The hint of Thomas finally lead me to Arduino's Info.plis entry `<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>` originally set to `<true/>`. Setting it to `<false/>`, Arduino starts fine using only the integrated graphics card reducing power consumption drastically on my Macbook Pro retina!

(Java 8-Update 111, Arduino 1.6.12)