# Setup adoptopenjdk 11 with key NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching

Tags: java, macos-mojave, adoptopenjdk, video-card

Can't solve problem with adoptopenjdk. I've to use key NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching in Info.plist
But Java using a discrete video card. What I'm doing wrong ?

```
<dict>
        <key>NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching</key>
        <string>YES</string>
...
</dict>
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40442206) help?

Comment: What else should I do besides setting this parameter in Info.plist? Java process starts from  Safari